# Adding up the numbers in a String java

Tags: java, android

I am trying to add up the characters in a String. But that doesn't seem to work. I am using this code:

```
public String createDeciOfOct (String number) {
    int result = 0;
    String[] numberArray = number.split("");
    for (String numb : numberArray) {
        if(numb != null || numb != "") {
            result += Integer.parseInt(numb);
        }
    }
    return Integer.toString(result);
}
```

How I am executing it is like this:

```
frmOctToDeci.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {            
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    EditText edtTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.octalValue);
    String value = edtTxt.getText().toString();
    String result = createDeciOfOct(value);
    TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fromOctRes);
    txtView.setText(result);
  }
});
```

It gives me an error as:

> `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""`

Which means that there is some sort of empty string. How can I prevent this?

The logcat errors are as:

[image]

Comment: What you expect to do when you split with `""` and you compare strings with `equals` , `==` is just for references

Comment: @nachokk, I want to skip it when there is no integer value there

Comment: Use equals when comparing strings

Comment: and a split with no split character... what does it lead to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Always use `equals()` for testing (in)equality between `String`s:

```
!numb.equals("")
```

Also it might be easier to process the input as a `char[]`, but that's just an idea:

```
char[] numberArray = number.toCharArray()
```

Then it's easy to convert a `char` to a digit, simply use `Character.getNumericValue()` on each `char` you wish to convert.

Comment: A nice a great solution, in both aspects! :) `char[]` would also be a great idea! :) However, I am a bit new to Java API that's why I am facing these troubles...

Answer (score 1):

That is wrong, so i edited it.

```
        if(numb != null || numb != "")
```

it should be (i thought, so it's still wrong)

```
        if(numb != null && numb != "")
```

Edit: the comment is right, i just wanted to notice the && instead of || . nevermind, forget it !

so it should **really** be:

```
        if(numb != null && ! numb .equals ("") )
```

of course ! "".equals(numb) does the same

Comment: No it should not :) When comparing strings, use `equals()`, not `==`

Comment: how i could not see that basic thing i will edit, but let mi first mistake for the future!

Answer (score 0):

**This algorithm will work:**

```
public String createDeciOfOct (String number) {
    int result = 0;

    for (int i = 0 ; i<number.length(); i++) {
        result = result + Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(number.charAt(i)));
    }
    return Integer.toString(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, as another answer state it, you should not use `!=` to compare strings, but `equals`.

Then, split takes a regexp and is a weird way of converting a String into an array of one-character string. I think it will be better to simply take the corresponding char array and use `Character.getNumericValue`

```
char[] charArray = number.toCharArray();
for (char c: charArray ) {
    result += Character.getNumericValue(numb);
}
```

Be carrefull, the code above does not perform any check to make sure your initial string contains only digit characters. If there are such characters the code will not fail but will produce unexpected result.